# How to configure Content-Security-Policy for Nginx and Drupal 8?

Tags: linux, nginx, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have a Nginx server with Ubuntu 18.04 and a Drupal 8 site.

I have read on several articles that should not use 'unsafe-eval', 'unsafe-inline'

I added headers for security but the pages of the site are no longer loaded correctly.

Here is my Nginx configuration and error messages :

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data:; base-uri 'self';";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header Feature-Policy "speaker 'none';";
```

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https: data:".
>   Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-Wtc+ZaqA71uBsN9DYJuo5jJMS66UuS5tCIAZnHYzzak='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

Comment: Did you change your web site after asking this question? I do not see the problem indicated here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I just changed the header `add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: data:; base-uri 'self';";` It works but I do not know if it's a good practice.

Comment: Can't you get rid of the inline styles?

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately no because there is a problem with ckeditor 4 and Drupal 8